# Django models adding member to a project

Tags: django, django-models

Trying to figure out how to create a Project class for an app I am making. I am bringing inn a Profile from another app, containing username, names and avatar. Then i need a project name and i want to be able to bring inn members, to the specific project, but don't know how to go forward with that.

models.py

```
from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE
from django.db import models
from profiles.models import Profile


class Projects(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=CASCADE)

    project_name    = models.CharField(max_length=55, null=True, blank=True)
    members         = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, related_name='projects')
```

Will add tasks, notes and a chat as seperate classes then bring them inn to the project as foreignkey, think that would be correct.

But how to deal with the members and get them added to the project?

Comment: `ManyToManyField(Profile, related_name='projects')`?

Comment: like the way I have updated it, what about the user from before?

Comment: well the `user` field can be used as the "owner", "manager" of a project, if there is no such role, then you can remove the user, and the `members` is thus then the entire collection of members.